# SetThreadDesktop not switching form to the other desktop

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, desktop

```
private async void WrongPassword_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr NEWDESKTOP = CreateDesktop("dew", IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, 0, (uint) DESKTOP_ACCESS.GENERIC_ALL,IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr OLDDESKTOP = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    SwitchDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);

    SetThreadDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);

    Thread.CurrentThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    ShowIcon = false;
    Text = "";
    TopMost = true;
    ControlBox = false;
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    button1.Enabled = false;
    MessageCycle();
    var i = 60;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        SoundPlayer dewd = new SoundPlayer(Resources.WrongPassword);
        dewd.PlaySync();
    });
    PlayMusic();
    while (i > 0)
    {
        CountDownLabel.Text = "Please wait " + i +
                     " seconds before you can dismiss to prevent \n DDOS, BRUTE FORCE ATTACKS";
        i = i - 1;
        Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    SetThreadDesktop(OLDDESKTOP);
    CloseDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);
    SwitchDesktop(OLDDESKTOP);
    CountDownLabel.Text = "We are not responsible if you lose your password and files";
    button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

When I put SetThreadDesktop(NEWDESKTOP), my form does not transfer from my current desktop to NEWDESKTOP, I have also put TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) and it still does not work, can someone give me a solution to how to transfer a form from your current desktop to NEWDESKTOP?

Comment: Then how do I transfer the form to the other desktop

Comment: You did try the CodeProject article?

Comment: Yes, but my main form is not transfering to the new desktop

Comment: This is what I want to identify, does The CodeProject article work? Is it your code or is there an actual bug here? If the CodeProject article works, its your code, if it doesn't well that's going to be pretty hard to troubleshoot because its a Win32 API written in C, at the device level in this case the Graphics card.

Comment: The CodeProject code does work, the new desktop shows a blank desktop and I am stuck unless I sign out because my main form does not transfer from my old desktop to the new desktop

Comment: If you add the Imgur links to screenshot pictures I will help you get the images to show (you need a certain rep score before you can do this yourself), that might help explain it a bit better. I think if you tell us what you're doing that would help. I understand you have a Winform app in C# and that you want to transfer it to a new desktop? I can't see the codeproject article on this PC, but does it show how to transfer the app with it's state to another desktop? Is that the ultimate goal you're working towards?

Comment: If its a sound player Window you can't close, one way would be to save the applications state (the song playing and the timecode) to a config/ini file, then `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(appPath);` and make it read the settings and start playing the song from the timecode.

Comment: Im just basically asking how do I open a form in the other desktop

Comment: Did the `SetThreadDesktop` function succeed. if it failed, try to use [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error?view=netcore-3.1) to get the error code.

Comment: Did you comment the `[STAThread]` before the Main() function I can get return value of true if I commented it, and then manually activate STA with `Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.TrySetApartmentState(Threading.ApartmentState.STA);` And also make sure that Don't use anything from user32.dll before you call `SetThreadDesktop`

Comment: I will show My samples below.

Answer (score 0):

Comments the `[STAThread]` and try to activate STA manually:
Also make sure that Don't use anything which will prevent you switching desktop before calling `SetThreadDesktop`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{

    static class Program
    {
        [Flags]
        internal enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            DESKTOP_NONE = 0,
            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x0001,
            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x0002,
            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x0004,
            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x0008,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x0010,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x0020,
            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x0040,
            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x0080,
            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x0100,
            GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000,
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateDesktop", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr CreateDesktop(
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string desktopName,
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string device, // must be null.
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string deviceMode, // must be null,
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,  // use 0
                    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] ACCESS_MASK accessMask,
                    IntPtr attributes);

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetThreadDesktop(uint dwThreadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int SetThreadDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int SwitchDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int CloseDesktop(IntPtr hDesktop);
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        //[STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            int ret = 0;
            IntPtr NEWDESKTOP = CreateDesktop("dew", null, null, 0, ACCESS_MASK.GENERIC_ALL, IntPtr.Zero);

            IntPtr OLDDESKTOP = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
            ret = SetThreadDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);
            ret = SwitchDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);

            Thread.CurrentThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            ret = SwitchDesktop(OLDDESKTOP);
            CloseDesktop(NEWDESKTOP);
        }
    }
}
```